# Why do I receive Invalid Password for some Hotmail Accounts while trying to connect through POP3?

Tags: c#, pop3, hotmail, openpop

I am making a software to check a list of hotmail accounts for something. I am using **OpenPop.NET** Library. The weird thing is that I get **Invalid Password Exception** with some accounts while I am sure that the password is correct because I can login without pop3 normally. I'd appreciate if someone can provide me an answer or an alternative way to connect to Hotmail inbox other than pop3 (Don't suggest using a Web Browser).

Here is the code I am using to connect:

```
 Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
            client.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995, true);
            var username = file[i].Split(':')[0];
            var pass = file[i].Split(':')[1];
            try
            {
                client.Authenticate(username, pass); //I am pretty sure that username,pass holds the right values.
                var msgs = client.GetMessageCount().ToString();
                updateList(i, msgs); //updates a listbox with message count for the hotmail account
            }
            catch (OpenPop.Pop3.Exceptions.InvalidPasswordException)
            {
                updateList(i, "Invalid Password");
            }
```

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the server response that I get from non-working accounts

```
The server didn't respond with +OK response. The response was: "-ERR mailbox could not be opened"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server is trying to prevent brutal force attacks !!! as you are checking credentials for a list of accounts. You may want to check the error message or inner-exception

Comment: That's not true. I thought that this might be the problem but according to my tests, the non-working account will never work sooner or later. It's weird.

Comment: In that case my guess would be that there could be a bug in the library you are using, do you want to try using the .net built in SMTP client its fairly simple and easy to use.

Comment: I believe SMTPClient is for sending emails.

Comment: Yes, System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Comment: I am one of the developers of OpenPop.NET. I do not believe there is any bugs in the authentication code - both unit tests and a lot of users is using it. Is there anything special about the usernames or passwords? Special characters or length? I actually believe such questions as this is better suited on the OpenPop.NET mailing list.